# Adding values to list using vlookup

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a big list like:

```
Actual:(sheet "A")          Expected:(Sheet "B")

A  Values                    A     Values
1    5                       1      5
3    12                      2      0
5    11                      3      12
                             4      0
                             5      11
```

I used formula =vlookup(A2, A!A2:A!B3, 2, FALSE) in B2 of sheet B and it returns "#N/A"

Comment: `A!A2:A!B3` remove the second `A!`? Edit: you might want to use `$` before the cells like `$A$2:$B$3`

Comment: Yup, got it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Sheet B, A2, use this: `=IfError(vlookup(A2,A!$A:$B,2,0),"No Match")`

Comment: Unless they are stuck in pre 2007 excel then use `=if(isna(vlookup(A2,A!$A:$B,2,0),"No Match",vlookup(A2,A!$A:$B,2,0))`

Comment: Yup, got it. Thanks :)